# Does "Leave the World Behind" take place in the same universe as "Mr. Robot"?

Tags: reference, mr-robot, leave-the-world-behind

For instance, we see an E-corp logo behind Amanda's laptop or on buckets in Danny's truck. Does this mean that it is indeed from the same universe?

Answer (score 2):

According to Sam Esmail himself, there is a single shared universe, and not just with *Mr Robot*

> It felt pretty natural, and to be honest with you, I didn’t just do it with Mr. Robot. There are little nods to everything I’ve worked on, from Homecoming and Comet to Robot. I fancy myself as creating my own little universe whenever I make a film, so I thought to myself, ‘Why not connect them all?’ It’s more fun that way.

> E-Corp’s logo appears on the buckets in Kevin Bacon’s character’s truck– they’re “5/9 Emergency Kits,” a reference to the date of a cyberattack that did shut down society on the show—as well as on Roberts’ laptop, and that at one point Roberts’ character is seen reading a book called Beach Towel, a novel published by Mr. Robot antagonist Otto Irving (Bobby Cannavale) during the show’s fourth season.

Source: [GQ - Confirmed: Leave the World Behind Takes Place in the Mr. Robot Extended Universe](https://www.gq.com/story/confirmed-leave-the-world-behind-takes-place-in-the-mr-robot-extended-universe)